# Cant render Component in switch statement in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, switch-statement, components, rendering

I have a ***registration*** view where in my table i have command to show modal with confirmation:

```
(...)               
render: (rowData) => (
  <button
    onClick={() => RenderModals(rowData, 'DELETE_USER_MODAL')}
  >
    Remove
  </button>
),
(...)
```

My ***RenderModals*** function looks like this:

```
type RenderModalProps = {
  data: any;
  modalCommand: string;
};

export const RenderModals = (data, modalCommand) => {
  console.log(data);
  switch (modalCommand) {
    case 'DELETE_USER_MODAL':
      return <DeleteUserModal data={data} />;
    case 'SOME_MODAL':
      return console.log('some modal');
    default:
      undefined;
  }
};
```

and I can see console.log(data) in the example above. But... I cant see any console.log from ***DeleteUserModal*** component.

***DeleteUserModal:***

```
type DeleteUserModalProps = {
  data: any;
};

export const DeleteUserModal = ({ data }: DeleteUserModalProps) => {
  console.log(`show data  ${data}`);
  return <div>some text...</div>;

};
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong ?

Why console.log from DeleteUserModal doesn't trigger?

Comment: You are never actually rendering the DeleteUserModal. All you are doing is returning it to the onClick function.

Comment: @RedFox - how can i render DeleteUserModal in such an arrangement of components as above?

Comment: The easiest way would probably be to assign the component to a variable in state and then render it.

Comment: Use `RenderModals` to set a boolean in state (like `showDeleteModal`), then conditionally render the modal in the return (`{state.showDeleteModal && <DeleteuserModal />}`).

Answer (score 0):

The way you currently have things set up, this would work:

```
class RegistrationExampleOne extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {component: null};
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={() => this.setState({component: RenderModals(rowData, 'DELETE_USER_MODAL')})}>Remove</button>
                {this.state.component}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Option one is not necessarily the better way of doing things, but it is more dynamic.

Option two (as mentioned in the comments by [@Brian Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9381601/brian-thompson)) would be similar to this:

```
import DeleteModal from './path';

class RegistrationExampleTwo extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {showDeleteModal: null};
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={() => this.setState({showDeleteModal: true})}>Remove</button>
                {this.state.showDeleteModal && <DeleteModal data={rowData} />}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```